# How to remove redundant data with skip and limit in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb

When we fetch data from db with skip and limit then it's very high chance that data may be redundant.

Let me explain you with an example 
suppose you are fetching those student records which belongs to some state x and you already fetched 10 student records. Between the time of first and second request one more student record is inserted, deleted or updated then in next query either one data row will come again or inserted data row will be skiped.

How to solve such case?

Answer (score 0):

Method - 1

It can be resolved by using sending 'Created_by' and 'Updated_by' time from UI and filter the data according to it and send the data.

Method - 2

In the second fetch request and there after skip one less then you want and increase limit by 1(Yes, its correct, think about it), and pass those data to UI now UI check the there current list data's last item should match the first item of fetched request's response(just compare by ids), then it mean that no single data added or removed after first query. If it's not match then fetch complete data from first to last in a single query.

If you use individual method then its not rock solid(Yes, some corner case will miss in each case) but if you combine both methods then it will be rock solid.